# MVC 4 : Creating dynamic dropdown list collection and read values in button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

can any one help me in below scenario.
i am getting list of students from different classess and creating dynamic drop down list.
in index method i am getting the list of students from different classes.
class 1  student names ex John , James,Martin.....
class 2  student names ex ex ricky,sam,joseph,......
class 3  student names ex steave,apple,.......
....
....
....
class n student collection ex {abc,xyz,.......}
now in my view based on the class count 
i am creating dropdown list and binding the student
    for(obj in class)
    {
drop down creation and bidning student names 
    }
till now every thing is working fine  .
can any one help me how to get the selected values on button click
for ex in clas 1 ,i will select JOhn 
and in class 2 , i will select Joseph
and in class 3 , i will select apple
now on button click i will go to another page , and i have to display as 
selected students

> class 1 :John Class 2: Joseph class 3: Apple .... ..... ..... class n
>   : xyz

Comment: How are you rendering your dropdown ?

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.DeviceBrand , new SelectList(Model.DeviceBrand , "Id", "BrandName"), "-Select Brand-")